# I want Android soft keyboard to have a "Done" button at the right moment WITHOUT JAVA

Tags: javascript, android, jquery-mobile, cordova, android-softkeyboard

I'm aware that questions have been asked and answered about the Android soft keyboard and which buttons it shows by default, and in what circumstances, and how to modify them.

However, all the answers involve changing the Java code. Since I am writing a cross-platform app using Phonegap and jQueryMobile, I'd like to stay away from learning Java.

My problem is this:
I have a form with (in this order, in abbreviated html):

```
<form action='javascript:processSubmit()'>
<select id='expenseType'/> 
<input type='text' id='expenseAmount'/>
<select id='expenseDate'/>
<button type='submit'/>
</form>
```

What currently happens is that the soft keyboard will appear once I press the text input field. So far so good. The button in the bottom right corner of the soft keyboard says 'Next'. But pressing it does not shift the focus to the next form field. And when the user has clicked on the second select and picked a value, the keyboard button does not change to 'Done'.

Is there not a way to give the fields some special html attribute to make the magic happen?

Or a Javascript way to change the softkeyboard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no way from JavaScript or HTML to affect the behavior of the Android soft keyboard.

Comment: I did find a few examples here and there where a bit of Java code exposes soft keyboard functionality to Javascript. But you're right, there's no direct access from Javascript or HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I know that is a very old question, but with this plugin https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-plugin-keyboard you can change this behaviour with the Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar method