# Manually set "Return" key alternative on Galaxy Ace

Tags: android, html, cordova, samsung-mobile, cordova-2.0.0

there is a simple app (html + js + phonegap) and a login form with these two inputs:

```
<form id="loginForm">
    <input type="email" id="email" value="" class="email" placeholder="Email" >
    <input type="password" id="password" value="" class="password" placeholder="Password" >
</form>
```

On a samsung galaxy ace (android 2.3.6) I want to transform the return key to a "Next" key on the email input, and in the password field I want the return key to be a "Go" (now I have a "Go" on the email and a return on the password).

How can I achieve this (using html/JS)?

Important: I'm using iScrol, note that if I remove iScroll I get a "Go" key in both inputs, so in a strange way this point may be relevant.

Short info about the return key: http://www.samsung.com/us/support/supportOwnersHowToGuidePopup.do?howto_guide_seq=6402

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated here: [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257830/i-want-android-soft-keyboard-to-have-a-done-button-at-the-right-moment-without)

*"there is no way from JavaScript or HTML to affect the behavior of the Android soft keyboard."*

I'll take this as the correct answer for now, but other answers are still welcome.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem you are facing is that after entering email the form is sent by the return key, then as you are using a HTML5 property 'placeholder' you can also use 'required' on the 'password' field, which won't allow a return action on the 'email' field to send it.

The [tabindex](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_tabindex.asp) HTML property might change the behavior of the return key.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but still no changes when using required and the tab indexes. I found that using iScroll changes the behavior of the keyboard (I'll update the question now).